# Is there any easy way to adjust the font size of a piece of text to fit into a certain area?

Tags: java

I need text to fill a predefined area. I don't necessarily want the fonts to grow beyond a certain limit, but I would prefer that it at least shrinks if it doesn't fit in a certain area. (So to have an upperbound on the font size, and also a lowerbound, but take the upperbound as default and scale down when required.)

Is there any easy way to get something like that done easily?

Comment: What's the UI techology that you use? Swing, SWT, output to HTML...

Comment: Do you mean text that will appear in a component like a JLabel or JTextArea or text that you are rendering directly during a paint() with drawString(). Will there be wrapping?

Comment: The answer really depends on the UI technology you're using. Is it Swing?

Comment: It could be Java2D directly, or otherwise just calculate the ideal font size and feed it into an SVG document. However, if there is an auto font resizing Swing component, I will consider that as well.

Comment: I am now looking at PdfSignatureAppearance.fitText(). The code looks a little awkward to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually ended up using the [fitText](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.2/itext-2.1.2-javadoc.jar!/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfSignatureAppearance.html#fitText%28com.lowagie.text.Font,%20java.lang.String,%20com.lowagie.text.Rectangle,%20float,%20int%29) operation on PdfSignatureAppearance, included in [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). That made it quite easy to get it done. It may not be perfect, but it's much better than not having anything at all.

```
public static final float calculateFontSize(String fontName, float maxFontsize, float width, float height, String text) {
    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(fontName);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(width, height);
    System.err.println("Calculating font size for " + width + " and " + height);
    return PdfSignatureAppearance.fitText(font, text, rectangle, maxFontsize, PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would hand pick the font sizes you want to use to make sure they look good on the target output.  No reason to stick to 3, use as many as you want.  The rectangle passed into getFont() must have x an y both set to 0.

```
public class FontFactory {
  private Font[] fonts;

  public FontFactory() {
    fonts = new Font[3];
    // font[0] = largest font
    // font[1] = middle font
    // font[2] = smallest font
  }

  public Font getFont(String string, Graphics g, Rectangle rectangle) {
    for (Font font : fonts) {
      Rectangle2D bounds = g.getFontMetrics(font).getStringBounds(string, g);
      if (rectangle.contains(bounds)) {
        return font;
      }
    }

    return fonts[fonts.length - 1];
  }
}
```